# Who can create /run/sshd directory on Raspberry-Pi if not ssh.service?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, sshd

I have an image of Raspberry-Pi, on which I am trying to make `sshd` running ("corrupted"). On another image, it is already runnung ("good").

On both images I have:

```
# cat ssh.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

i.e. no `RuntimeDirectory` directive. Nevertheless, "good" image starts `ssh`, while "corrupted" one does not.

```
#systemctl start ssh
```

fails.

If I create directory by hands

```
mkdir /run/sshd
```

the command

```
#systemctl start ssh
```

is starting to work.

The question is: how is it possible for `ssh` service to work without `RuntimeDirectory` directive? Who can create it for it?

Answer (score 0):

On elder versions on `systemd`, like on `Raspberry Pi`, this directory is created via

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf
```